# Hibernate: performance issue due to relationships

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Using Hibernate Tools 4.0.0, I generate entity classes for my SpringMVC-Hibernate-Oracle web application with Jackson lib for JSON conversion. I need annotation based classes, hence I have configured the tool accordingly.

The relationships & constraints are appropriately defined in the database. As a  result, the entity classes get generated with 2 types of annotations on the joining columns -

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
// I modified to @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUST_CODE")
```

and

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tempCustHeader")
```

I have a been experiencing a pretty bad performance, obviously because in case of EAGER fetch, Hibernate tries to fetch data for all dependent classes upfront.

I changed the FetchType back to LAZY and the performance remained as bad as before.

I noticed that when Jackson lib tries to convert data into JSON, at the time of returning the response, all the data in the ManyToOne relationship with FetchType.LAZY is also retrieved. Thus, no matter LAZY or EAGER, it takes almost same amount of time & size of data while responding.

My question - How to improve performance by managing relationships correctly? If I remove the relationships, either from DB or only from entity classes, it would mean that I am not making use of Hibernate's capabilities. How are such scenarios handled in other projects?

Comment: The problem is not with the associations. The problem is in the way you're serializing the entities to JSON. Add Jackson annotations to make it ignore the associations you don't want to serialize.

Comment: Or create DTOs that lack the relationships you don't want to send, and then serialize those instead.

Comment: Do you use Service Bean in order to transform your Entity beans into an unlinked bean (DTO)? I hope you do not inject your DAO directly to your Controller bean.

Comment: @IanMcLaird - I have done exactly the same thing that you have suggested. But, I am not sure if this is correct practice. I have a service layer to do that. I don't directly inject the DAO in the Controller.

Comment: But do you tranform your entity bean in another bean (unlinked to database, called DTO), and applying the JSON transformation to the DTO and not to the Entity. Can you publish your code (or sample) of your service layer in the question?